# Remove time from ISO date to filter with Vapor Swift

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to figure out how to filter ISO dates. I'd like to filter out Todo's for a specific day.

Dates are save in the database like this:

```
"started" -> 2022-03-17 18:46:44+00
```

I'd like to filter "started" like so

```
2022-03-17
```

Here's my query. I can't figure out a way to remove the time from the date.

```
func indexTodosByDate(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Todo]> {
    guard let dateFilter = req.parameters.get("date", as: Date.self) else {
        throw Abort(.badRequest)
    }   
    return Todo.query(on: req.db)
        .filter(\.$started == dateFilter)
        .with(\.$user)
        .all()
}
```

Comment: Please clarify, is the date stored with date and time or is it stored as the complete string "started" -> 2022-03-17 18:46:44+00"? And while clarifying, if it is the former then is it stored as a Date or a String?

Comment: Stored as the complete string "2022-03-17 18:46:44+00". ISO8601

Comment: A bit of a hack but you could split the string on " " to get the date. Off topic but that is not a ISO 6801 date format, then you should have a T and not a space between the date and the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst @0xTim has identified the correct method, I hope this will give you the necessary code to achieve what you want.

First, extend Date to give you midnight on the date in question:

```swift
extension Date {
    var midnight: Date { return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)! }
}
```

Then, use this in a query's filter:

```swift
let query = ToDo(on: database).filter(\.$started >= dateFilter.midnight)
```

Comment: Note that Calendar has a [startOfDay(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293783-startofday) function

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the standard date formats and it's using a `datetime` as the field type in your migration, you can't.

What you need to do is write a query that searches for date is greater than or equal to the day at 00:00 and less than or equal to 23:59 etc. Do work out the start of the day and end of the day and pass that to your filters. Swift's `Calendar` APIs have functions to get the start of a day